Github API to encrypt new token and update a secret with encrypted token in Github Workflow yaml script
I am trying to replace the access token stored as a secret in Github Secrets & Variables via Github Actions but couldn't find a way to do encryption on new access token using libsodium (https://docs.github.com/en/rest/actions/secrets?apiVersion=2022-11-28#create-or-update-an-organization-secret). Here below is the workflow script which I have created and I am currently stuck at the point where id - encrypt_access_token. I created a script to process the encryption but found no way to develop the script in python. A reference using Javascript can be found in GitHub API secret encryption with libsodium in Node.js: UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: bad public key size. Anyone has experience in this?
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
  schedule:
    - cron: '0 0 * * *'
    
jobs:
  refresh-token:
    runs-on: [self-hosted, 2-core]

    steps:
      - name: Checkout Code
        uses: actions/checkout@v4
        
      - name: Set Up Python
        uses: actions/setup-python@v4
        with:
          python-version: '3.10'
          
      - name: Refresh OAuth Token
        run: |
          curl --request POST \
            --url https://xxxx/oauth/token \
            --header "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" \
            --data "client_id=${{ secrets.CLIENT_ID }}" \
            --data "client_secret=${{ secrets.CLIENT_SECRET }}" \
            --data "refresh_token=${{ secrets.REFRESH_TOKEN }}" \
            --data "grant_type=client_credentials" \
            --output response.json
          
          echo "NEW_ACCESS_TOKEN=$(cat response.json | jq -r '.access_token')" >> $GITHUB_ENV

      - name: Get GitHub Repository Public Key (for secret encryption)
        id: get_public_key
        run: |
          curl -s -H "Authorization: token ${{ secrets.GH_PAT }}" \
            -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" \
            -H "X-GitHub-Api-Version: 2022-11-28" \
            https://api.github.com/repos/${{ github.repository }}/actions/secrets/public-key \
            > public_key.json
          echo "KEY_ID=$(cat public_key.json | jq -r '.key_id')" >> $GITHUB_ENV
          echo "PUBLIC_KEY=$(cat public_key.json | jq -r '.key')" >> $GITHUB_ENV
                
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: |
          python -m pip install --upgrade pip
          pip install pynacl

      - name: Encrypt the New Access Token
        id: encrypt_access_token
        run: |
          echo "ENCRYPTED_ACCESS_TOKEN=$(python secret_encryptor.py)" >> $GITHUB_ENV
          
      - name: Update the Access Token Secret Using GitHub API
        run: |
          curl -X PUT -H "Authorization: token ${{ secrets.GH_PAT }}" \
          -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
          -d '{"encrypted_value":"'"${{ env.ENCRYPTED_ACCESS_TOKEN }}"'","key_id":"'"${{ env.KEY_ID }}"'"}' \
          https://api.github.com/repos/${{ github.repository }}/actions/secrets/ACCESS_TOKEN

a python script using libsodium to encrypt new token and update the secret stored in Github

Got the workaround referring to https://stackoverflow.com/a/68975720/26400325. I am using Github CLI (gh secret command) and it works.
